# Retrieving data using Json using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
      var city;

      function getCity(){ 
         $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
            city= data.city;
            alert(city);
         });
       }

       getCity();
       alert(city);
```

I am alerting the same  city variable two times, one inside the function getcity() and another at last. But they both gives different values. Inside the function gives current city but out side the function gives undefined. I want to get current city on both.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous....

Answer (score 4):

AJAX is asyncronous.
That means that `getCity` will retrieve data at some later point but your script will not stop, and will trigger `alert(city)` which currelty holds no value (undefined)

**Use a callback like:**

```js
function getCity( callback ){ 
  $.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function(data) {
    var city= data.city;
    alert(city);
    callback( city );
  });
}


getCity(function( city ){
   alert(city);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Roko C. Buljan. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `$.getJSON` is asynchonous; it will go and fetch the specified URL in the background, then run the function you pass to the second parameter when it is completed. Meanwhile, you can carry on doing other stuff while it is fetching the requested data.

This means that your control flow looks something like the following:

- Declare city - value `undefined`.
- Call `getCity`.

  - `getCity` will fire off the asynchronous request in the background.
  - `getCity` then exits.
- Print out the contents of `city` - still `undefined.
- At some point in the future, `getJSON` will have completed, and will call the specified function.

  - The callback will assign to `city` and print it out.

There's not really a nice way to ensure that `city` is set after `getCity` has executed - you should try and move your logic that requires `city` to be set inside the callback instead.

Comment: Thank You slugonamission for you explanation. It helped me to understand where i was wrong.